# Is it possible to integrate 302 based auth with 401 based auth?

Tags: authentication, passwords, web-application

I'm looking at securing endpoints with a technique similar to HAWK which returns a 401 authentication with OAuth which uses 302 based redirection

How can I combine two different authentication formats such that a smart client will be able to handle the HAWK implementation

Comment: Eh, what's HAWK, doc?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk Mozilla also has posts on it

Comment: See also this: (Hawk may have a CSRF vulnerability)  http://stackoverflow.com/q/41885509/328397